# Unable toggle an element ON in site (Bootstrap)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to turn the toggle ON an element. But failing !
Please advise.

Below is the HTML Code

```
<div id="failureSwitch" style="display: block; width: auto; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px; float: left; position: relative;" xpath="1">
            
            <label class="text-uppercase">Show Failure Counts</label>
            <div class="onoffswitch">
                <input type="checkbox" name="myonoffswitchforedit" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitchforfailure" onclick="ToggleFailures();">
                <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitchforfailure">
                    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have tried using the below Selenium Code but in vain !

```
WebElement option1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='myonoffswitchforfailure']"));    
if (option1.isSelected()) {                 
    System.out.println("Checkbox is Toggled On");                   

} else {            
    System.out.println("Checkbox is Toggled Off");
    //option1.click();  
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement passwordElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='myonoffswitchforfailure']")));           
    passwordElement.click();
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Error i am getting with WebDriver Wait
`*Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath:` //input[@id='myonoffswitch'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)*

Error i am getting without WebDriver Wait -
`*element not interactable*

Comment: Please advise on how to proceed.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the url? or please share the complete error message you get when you are not using WebDriverWait